# Underline Text wrapped in another View

Tags: swiftui

The SwiftUI modifier `.underline()` can be used to underline Text:

```
Text("Hello").underline()
```

Similarly, the modifier `.font(…)` can be used to change to font of text:

```
Text("A nice picture").font(.caption)
```

The `.font(…)` modifier also works on any `View` as well as a `Text`, so you can use `.font()` on a `Group` or `HStack` or your own `View` conforming `struct`. Doing so will change the font used by `Text` in that `View` – sweet. If I look up `.font()`, I can see it's an extension on `View`, so this makes sense, although seems rather magical!

However, the `.underline()` modifier *can't* (as far as I can tell) be used on any `View` to cause `Text` in it to be underlined. Similarly, `.strikethrough()` and `.italic()` and lots of other `Text` modifiers aren't available. They're defined as an extension on `Text`, so only work on this type.

I was wondering:

- Is there a nice solution for this so that I can `.underline()` on parent view to get underlining on its contained `Text` children?
- Why is SwiftUI currently like this?

Comment: There is no underline on a View. Here is a link where the solution is to extend Text with a new protocol TextModifier. That would abstract the style, but each Text would need its own modifier. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132627

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a built-in way. Maybe you could create a custom `StyledText` view that supports text styles passed via Environment